# How to use PowerShell console in 10.3

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

Using `Sitecore 10.3`

This is a local instance. I have opened the `PowerShell console` and it shows up like this.
The yellow notification bar doesn't go.
How do I get to the command prompt?

[image]

Clicking on `Drop elevated session state` does nothing.

Comment: Any errors in javascript console of the browser?

Comment: @MarekMusielak No errors in console

Comment: @sukesh Is the `Drop elevated session state` clickable? If yes what happens when you click?

Comment: You need to add or enable the Identity Server configuration.

Comment: @MichaelWest This is a fresh instance. Do I need to make changes here too. Will installing SPE not be enough?

Answer (score 0):

`SPE elevated rights` means that SPE has put a named token in your session state that has an expiration time. We are not elevating anything related to any other aspect of your `Sitecore environment` – you’re `SPE elevated` which means we allow you to do execute `Script` and save it within your `Sitecore environment`.

If you want to hide yellow notification bar  `Powershell console` and allow elevation of the user session. You can update the configuration via patch file for `Console` window only in `Spe.config`.

```
<token name="Console" expiration="00:05:00" elevationAction="Allow"/>
```

Once you allow the console window, the result will be.

[image]

[image]

The console app is a decent entry point when you need to quickly provide a `one liner` to test something or just change a field in a large number of items.

**Credit** & Refer for more details:

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/security

https://sitecorepowershell.com/session-state-elevation/

Hope it helps!

Comment: How do I get to the command prompt was my question. I don't mind the yellow bar.

Comment: Check if any error logged in SPE.log file while accessing console.